# How To use @ symbol in jquery in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use @ symbol in javascript in if condition. but it is showing me an error.

```
if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) {
                    alert('yes');
                    strength += 1
                }
```

It is Showing me this error. 
[image]

Comment: Error messages should be copied into the question. Do not paste images of them.

Comment: ok. I will follow afterwords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can type it twice as shown below:

```
if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) {
    alert('yes');
    strength += 1
}
```

Since `@` is a special character for razor syntax. You can escape it by typing another `@`

**UPDATE**

Since you are trying it in regex and as mentioned, `@@` just solves the compilation error but gives wrong results while using the regex, please try:

```
if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@('@'),#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@('@'),#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) {
    alert('yes');
    strength += 1
}
```

The `@('@')` will be converted into `@` by razor and should give you the desired result.

Comment: Bro it's not working. It is just removing error not working as i want. @priyank

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the above condition and it's working fine

[image]

Can you please share all code so we can easily identify your issue.

and another one You can type it twice as shown below:

```
if (password.match(/(.*[!,%,&,@@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~].*[!,%,&,@@,#,$,^,*,?,_,~])/)) {
alert('yes');
strength += 1
```

}

in razor @@ will escape that.

Comment: How is this a different answer than the one which was already provided?

Comment: @PriyankPanchal , when I write a post at that time, not any comment were there, and it might happen that some answer is common for some question

Comment: @PriyankPanchal, about escape we both are right, but still, I have check without the escape of @, in the console and its working fine, so that's why I thought something else is missing, 
what you think ??
did you try on console  ?

Comment: We cannot try this on console because `@` is a special symbol for razor `.cshtml` files. On console it will always work fine, but will give errors only when used in razor file.

Comment: on razor page it is not working. i am using if condition. if user enter @ for single time than it need to alert 'yes'. but now when i am writing two @ than it is giving me 'yes' alert.

Comment: @LovePandey, Please Edit and  write more description, so we can check further.