# How to use JavaScript '@' on MVC page. Error - {"\"') + 1);\" is not valid at the start of a code block

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have code block where I need to use a '@' character to get an index of the Email Id to check it's domain.

I have put it on a same page of Asp.Net Mvc like below:

```
function SubmitForm()
        {
            var allDomains = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedDomain"]';
            var allowedDomains = alDomains.split(';');

            var emailText = document.getElementById('Email').value;
            if (emailText != null) {
                var emailDomain = emailText.substr(emailText.indexOf('@') + 1);
                if (allowedDomains.length > 0 && allowedDomains.includes(emailDomain))
                  alert("Email error");
            }
                $("#newForm").submit();
        }
```

When I try to get and index of '@' character on Asp.Net MVC page, it is giving me an error

```
{"\"') + 1);\" is not valid at the start of a code block.
```

Any idea how I can use '@' to get an index of it?

Update: Able to use it by adding '@@' instead of '@'.

Comment: have you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520980/how-to-use-symbol-in-jquery-in-mvc

Comment: Duplicate: [How To use @ symbol in jquery in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520980/how-to-use-symbol-in-jquery-in-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to possible answers. Have figured it out to make it work.